# Folder copied by Docker inaccessible in Jenkins

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

I have a docker image that I want to use with Jenkins, but I cannot access a folder. I have a feeling that the the ubuntu jenkins user just cannot see/access the folder copied when the Dockerfile is built. Below is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM jaas/jdk8-jenkins-slave:latest

USER root
RUN apt-get update -y 
    && apt-get upgrade -y 
    && apt-get install git -y 
COPY ./ModusToolbox_2.1.0.1266-linux-install.tar.gz ./
RUN tar -xzf ModusToolbox_2.1.0.1266-linux-install.tar.gz 
    && rm ModusToolbox_2.1.0.1266-linux-install.tar.gz 

USER jenkins
RUN date +%a-%b-%d-%Y:%Z-%H:%M > openshift/BUILD_DAT
```

Is there any way I could make the file extracted from the .tar.gz visible to the jenkins user? I have tried looking around on how to share folders between users, but it didn't seem to work... Finally, the only directory I can access in jenkins is /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/ModusJenkins, but changing the docker file to extract the .tar.gz to this directory didn't work, as when I did "ls" in the jenkins execute build step, it showed nothing.

Any suggestions/advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: on the basis of above (if you are running CMD from proper location) i can say that, you are copying files as root user and then changing USER to Jenkins (will be having lower privileges then root ) to write date in folder owned by root. Move USER jenkins above COPY cmd.

Comment: I moved USER jenkins above COPY, but that didn't solve the issue. Is there any way I can access the files after I copy it? Is there a way I can access this within Jenkins?